# ERROR 1136 on DELETE

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have this code and when I try the delete sentence on HeidiSQL it gives me this:
"ERROR 1136: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"
I don't really understand why is this happening when I have another 2 trigger/delete that works perfect.
This is the code:

```
$triggersSQL="CREATE TRIGGER dev_cs BEFORE DELETE ON caja_sb FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        DECLARE cod_est varchar(11);
        DECLARE cod_lej varchar(4);

    SET cod_est = '$codE';
    SET cod_lej = '$cod';

    INSERT INTO caja_sorpresa VALUES (null, '$codCaja', '$anch', '$alt', '$prof', '$color', '$cont', NOW(), '$cod');

    UPDATE estanteria
    SET estanteria.lejas_ocupadas=estanteria.lejas_ocupadas+1
    WHERE estanteria.codigo_estan=cod_est;

    UPDATE leja
    SET leja.ocupacion='1'
    WHERE leja.cod_leja=cod_lej;

    END";

    $conexion->query($triggersSQL);

    $ordenSQL="DELETE FROM caja_sb WHERE codigo_caja='$codCaja'";
    $resultado=$conexion->query($ordenSQL);
```

the variables have the correct data.

Comment: How many columns are in your table? You're passing in 9 values. You can try specifying the columns in your INSERT query.

Comment: OMG you're right, ok it was a really stupid mistake, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says:

> INSERT INTO caja_sorpresa VALUES (null, '$codCaja', '$anch', '$alt', '$prof', '$color', '$cont', NOW(), '$cod');

That means, the number of values you are writting in the VALUES() does not correspond to the value of fields in the table.
If you want to insert data without specifying values for each column, than you would have to use a syntax like:

> INSERT INTO tablename(column1, column2) VALUES(value1, value2);